# Как v-repeat преобразовать в v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, как преобразовать?

```
<th v-repeat="options.cols">{{$index}}</th>
```

в

```
<th v-for="options.cols">{{$index}}</th>
```

Должно заполнить заголовки от 0 до 4.
Спасибо.

```js
var grid = new Vue({
  el: "#grid",
  data: {
    options: {
      rows: 5,
      cols: 5
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <!-- КАК ПРЕОБРАЗОВАТЬ? ?? -->
      <th v-repeat="options.cols">{{$index}}</th>
      <!-- <th v-for="options.cols">{{$index}}</th> -->
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Смотрим документацию](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    cols: 5
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <div v-for="(i, _i) in cols" :key="_i">{{ i }}, {{ _i }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уважаемый Other! Большое Вам спасибо!